# Spring Boot LDAP - pooled property for auto configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ldap, spring-config

In Spring Boot I can pass properties which will be picked for auto configuration:

- spring.ldap.url
- spring.ldap.username
- spring.ldap.password

Is there any `spring.ldap.*` property to set `pooled=true` to avoid using explicit LdapTemplate config?

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
contextSource.setPooled(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) that lists all of the Spring Boot properties, no. I also looked at the [LdapProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ldap/LdapProperties.java) class which stores these values at runtime and didn't see anything in there that would help with pooling. I suspect you'll have to keep doing this manually.

Perhaps file a PR on them? They seem open to adding things if there is a need in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that I have read on this recommends that configuration be done using the PoolingContextSource.  The LDAP authentication process requires a two-stage process that is problematic.  The below is from the blog of Mattias Hellborg Arthursson, a Spring LDAP guru.

> Built-in JNDI Connection Pooling
>
> The pooled property of ContextSource has previously defaulted to true,
>   enabling the built-in Java LDAP connection pooling by default. However
>   the built-in LDAP connection pooling suffers from several deficiencies
>   (most notable there is no way of doing connection validation and
>   configuration is cumbersome), which is why we decided to change the
>   default to false . If you require connection pooling we strongly
>   recommend using the Spring LDAP PoolingContextSource instead.

https://blog.jayway.com/2008/10/27/whats-new-in-spring-ldap-13/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/pooling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set ldap pool properties with JVM parameters. You specify them when launching your application.

For example:

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize=10 
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize=5 
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=300000
```